# Monitoring complex applications with Application Insights?

Tags: application-insights

I have a problem being tasked with setting up application monitoring for a complex application that has multiple web elements (some asp.net applications, some pure api endpoints) as well as mobile apps (which are of less interest for me and for now can be treated a little isolated).

It looks like application insight is "the best" solution so far, also from a cost perspective.

But: it also seems applicaiton insight is not really handling distributed applications well.

What is the recommended way to do things for a non-trivial setup?

- If I make one application insights ressource, I can get all metrics etc. in one bucket, including all API calls across all levels, but I have to filter out to see for example metrics for one website only. For that I will have to somehow misuse the tagging mechanism described in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/, iirc.
- If I make multiple ressources, then "the bucket stops at ressource borders". So, a UI making a backend call will not get the performance from the sql statement in the UI, iirc, because the API will use a separte instrumentation key.

That leaves me somewhere undecided. Any advice? There is little discussion around that google points me to and all cases seem to assume a very simplistic application setup (one website).